# How to only keep the same number of rows for certain name between two files?

Tags: r

given two files

df1

```
df1=read.table("C:\\file1.txt", sep="")
Value   name
  0.2    sam
  0.4  david
  3    david
  7    nicola
```

df2

```
File2=read.table("C:\\file2.txt", sep="")
Value   name
  0.8 nicola
  0.9  david
```

Keep only rows where names exist in both files. For instance, desired outputs:

File 1

```
Value   name
  7  nicola
```

File 2

```
Value   name
  0.8  nicola
```

Comment: If there were 2 david and 2 david iin both files, will you keep that both rows

Comment: It's not a dupe of that link, so reopening that.

Comment: I meant the sample of original datasets so that I can test the code instead of the tbl output

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
tbl1 <- table(df1$name)
tbl2 <- table(df2$name)
i1 <- names(tbl1) %in% names(tbl2)
nm1 <- names(tbl1)[tbl1[i1]==tbl2[i1]]
df1[df1$name %in% nm1,]
#  Value   name
#4     7 nicola

i2 <- names(tbl2) %in% names(tbl1)
i21 <- tbl2[i2]==tbl1[intersect(names(tbl1), names(tbl2[i2]))]

nm2 <- names(i21)[i21]
df2[df2$name %in% nm2,]
#   Value   name
#1   0.8 nicola
```

Comment: @temor I haven't tested it.  But, hope so.

Comment: @temor My code was based on the example provided.  You can try similar to the second code block

Comment: @temor I mean, try to do the same as I have done with `i2 <-`  or if you can show some small example that gives the error, I can change the code.

Comment: @temor Please do update the new data iin your post so that I can test it.